# Maven standardized support for multi-releases jars

Tags: maven, java-9

Java 9 released with [JEP-238](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238), which basically allows us to ship multiple versions of runtime classes. The question is how this JEP is supported by maven?

- I mean how and where to configure multiple versions in maven? I know I can run an ant task, but can I do it with say maven-compiler plugin or another standardized way?
- And where and how should I place the different versions of java classes? JEP is constraining the compiled class files and say us where we should place it in jar but what about development?

Comment: Yes, I also voted to close. Individually, each of those questions is quite interesting, though (although I'm afraid the answers will be rather disappointing).

Comment: Edited question to be only maven related.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no standard support for multi-release jars in Maven yet. However, there are 3rd party plugins available, e.g.: https://github.com/metlos/multi-release-jar-maven-plugin

Comment: Maven does not yet support that but there is a work around http://in.relation.to/2017/02/13/building-multi-release-jars-with-maven/

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/multirelease.html lists multiple possible approaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean how and where to configure multiple versions in maven? I know I
>   can run an ant task, but can I do it with say maven-compiler plugin or
>   another standardized way?

I believe the `maven-compiler-plugin` is not the appropriate place to take care of the release or even if we say ant tasks. Its supposed to be compiling the sources of a project seeking the need of which it has though introduced a flag

```
-release N
```

whose usage seems similar to that of the `-source N` and `-target N`.

It shall compile for a specific VM version(N) and shall support targets: 6, 7, 8, 9. It is similar to the new flag introduced in `javac` as

```
--release <release>
```

The java way of creating a multi-release jar, placing some files in the `META-INF/versions/9` directory after this shall be of the format :

```
jar --create --file mr.jar -C foo classes --release 9 -C foo9 classes
```

In terms of MR-JAR maven implementation, one of the alternates currently could be as linked by [@simas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557575/maven-standartized-support-for-multi-releases-jars#comment80071714_46557575) or listed below as proposals(couldn't get to find their released implementations) in one of the analysis.

<sub>**Note**: Shouldn't one rather be interested in moving to `JMOD`s instead of considering `MR-JAR` for versions 9 and later?</sub>

> And where and how should I place the different versions of java
>   classes?

In the document [Java 9 and its Impact on Maven Projects](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Java9%20and%20the%20impact%20on%20Maven%20projects.pdf), the proposals to solve for the MR-JAR has been to either keep a 1 to 1 translation to the structure as mentioned in the *[JEP-238](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238)*

```
project root
 src/main/java
 - A.java
 - B.java
 - C.java
 - D.java
 src/main/java9
 - A.java
 - B.java
 src/main/java10
 - A.java
```

which though can work with different `executions` in maven but could possibly be inconvenient to be exposed to IDEs.

Another alternate with a sample [hboutemy/maven-jep238](https://github.com/hboutemy/maven-jep238) has been listed with the same to make use of following structure:-

```
multimodule root
 multirelease-base/src/main/java
 - A.java
 - B.java
 - C.java
 - D.java
 multirelease-nine/src/main/java
 - A.java
 - B.java
 multirelease-ten/src/main/java
 - A.java
 multirelease/src/assembly/mvjar.xml
```

---

### October 4, 2017

I couldn't find an official documentation or implementation where these proposals are consumed by an open source/organisation, hence inferring its *not very plainly possible using Maven currently*.

Comment: should we wait for standard support and then rewrite that answer? The current version of answer is correct of course)

Comment: @TolegenIzbassar Ideally **Yes**, though in my opinion that should not stop you from experimenting and devising things like the  https://github.com/metlos/multi-release-jar-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

[SLF4J](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j) seems to get this working with multiple modules.

Comment: SLF4J builds a multi-release jar in order to support JMPS/JIGSAW modules. However, the solution adopted in SLF4J has drawbacks. In particular, IDE integration is zero in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

There are two examples how to process JEP-238 with Maven

1. [Example how to build JEP-238 oriented maven project organized as a
   multi-module one](https://github.com/hboutemy/maven-jep238)
2. [Example of single-module maven project with
   preprocessing](https://github.com/raydac/jep-238-jcp-example)